# Open app for specific filetype (from email attachment)

Tags: android, mime-types, email-attachments

As per my study to support a filetype applying filter to an Activity should be enough,

```
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

          <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.filetype"/>
          <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.filetype"/>
          <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.filetype"/>
          <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.filetype"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But it does not work for email attachments. When try to open the attachments it only show a message, that no support app found for this filetype.

This snipped code works for email attachments,

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fileType" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But for this filter, my application appears for any kind of filetype.

So my question is,

1.What is the proper way to open an email attachment with my app? So that myapp try to open only for the specific filetype.

Answer (score 0):

You need a launcher default to launch based on type.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.gosylvester.bestrides.ImageTextListViewActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```